# JavaFX WebEngine - action on hyperlink

Tags: java, browser, javafx

I have an embedded web browser using JAVA FX javafx.scene.web.WebEngine class. What we need is to inform JAVA about clicking on some hyperlink (for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions). Therefore I expect that I need to:

1. to detect some specific hyperlink (https://stackoverflow.com/questions),
2. do some action (e.g. print some text to console) and
3. veto redirection to a new URL (keep on the original page).

EDIT:
Below is my code, that still redirects the page to new destination:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker;
import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.events.Event;
import org.w3c.dom.events.EventListener;
import org.w3c.dom.events.EventTarget;

public class WebViewSample extends Application {
    private Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        // create the scene
        stage.setTitle("Web View");
        scene = new Scene(new Browser(), 750, 500, Color.web("#666970"));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

class Browser extends Region {

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();

    public Browser() {
        // apply the styles
        getStyleClass().add("browser");
        // load the web page
        webEngine.load("http://stackoverflow.com");
        // add the web view to the scene
        getChildren().add(browser);

        webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {
            public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
                if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        // note next classes are from org.w3c.dom domain
                    EventListener listener = new EventListener() {
                        public void handleEvent(Event ev) {
                            String href = ((Element)ev.getTarget()).getAttribute("href");
                            if(href.startsWith("/questions")) {
                                System.out.println("Action trigered");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Clicked on the link "+href);
                            }
                        }
                    };

                    Document doc = webEngine.getDocument();
                    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("a");
                    for (int i=0; i<list.getLength(); i++) {
                        ((EventTarget)list.item(i)).addEventListener("click", listener, false);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.